# Android: Disable scolling on an element, inside a listview

Tags: android, listview, scroll

Hy!

I have a listview in an activity.
In the listview there are more LinealLayout. One of them has two imageview. For both imageView is setup ontuchlistener. Is it possible not to scroll the listview, if user try to scroll over that layout? can i somehow owerride listview scrolling?

> base_activity.xml:

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/items"
    style="@style/ListViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>
```

> item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_with_image">

                <ImageView />

                <ImageView />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> itemAdapter.java:

```
       imgButton1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    // Ignore move events
                    return false;
                }
                if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    doPressDown(1, orderItem);
                }
                else if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    doPressRelease();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        imgButton1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    doPressDown(-1, orderItem);
                }
                else if (event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    doPressRelease();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes that is possible by disallowing interception touch events of parent view.To disallow, use [requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)) method of view group. Such as;

```
anyView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: getParent a bit comlicated, so i used interface to access scrollView. requestDisallowInterceptionTouchEvent() method was usefull, thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `onTouch` for your listview to return true if the touch event is equal to `ACTION_MOVE`, disabling the scrolling movement.

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Create a boolean variable 'scrollable' that can be toggled true/false
        if (!scrollable)
            return (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE.equals(event.getAction()));
        else
            return false;
    }
});
```

Another option is to disable the listview, however, this will also disable row selection:

```
listView.setEnabled(false);
```